# If ActiveRecord::Base.transaction succeeded, do something

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I check whether a ActiveRecord::Base.transaction succeded?

I want the rollback to happen if something goes wrong, but I also want to make sure that if the transaction has succeeded I do some extra logic. Here is the code:

```
#...
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  user_id = existing_ids.last || User.create(phone: phone_number)
  homes.update_all(user_id: user_id)
end

if transaction_was_success
  # do something
else 
  # do something else
end
```

Comment: What is the context of the transaction? Where are you putting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preform extra work after a successful transaction, you can use an `after_commit` callback.

To trigger a rollback when a failure occurs during a transaction, use `!` methods. The problem with using the `update_all` method is that it will not raise any errors. `update_attribute!` is an `!` method so it will raise an error on failure. This will now rollback the transaction if any update or create fails.

```
after_commit :successful_commit

ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  user_id = existing_ids.last || User.create!(phone: phone_number)
  homes.each do |home|
     home.update_attribute!(user_id: user_id)
  end

  # Or do other things here...
end

def successful_commit
   # Something on success here...
end
```